# jquery find closest previous sibling that does not have class

Tags: jquery, css, dom

I am stumped at trying to get the closest previous element with class 'slide' that does NOT contain class 'subsection' using jQuery

Sample HTML:

```
<section id="p1" class="slide"></section>
<section id="p2" class="slide"></section>
<section id="p3" class="slide"></section> <!--I AM TRYING TO GET THIS ELEM -->
<section id="p31" class="slide subsection"></section>
<section id="p32" class="slide subsection"></section> <!--I AM HERE -->
<section id="p4" class="slide"></section>
```

I have tried: (where $subsection is the element indicated above)

```
var $slide = $subsection.prev('.slide').not('.subsection');
var $slide = $subsection.prev('.slide:not(".subsection")');
var $slide = $subsection.prev('.slide').not("[class='subsection']");
var $slide = $subsection.prev('.slide:not([class="subsection"])');
```

Now I found out that prev() only selects a single previous elem and then stops, but prevUntil doesn't work either?

```
var $slide = $subsection.prevUntil('.slide').not('.subsection');
```

I also tried:

```
var $slide = $subsection.prevAll('.slide').not('.subsection');
```

but this gets me the very first slide element with id p1.

If anyone has any tips I'd appreciate it...
Can anyone stop me going cray cray? 8-|

Comment: If you need to do this, perhaps you should question whether your CSS class/HTML element structure should be simpler & more easily navigable?

Comment: I thought this should be easy enough .. the 'closest' slide that does not have class subsection. It wouldn't be hard to adjust to a nested structure, but adding subsections using this structure enables the CSS to work without additional changes.

Comment: ...and it was super simple in the end, thanks to @Hiral pointing out the answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
var a = $("#p32").prevAll(".slide").not(".subsection").first();
alert($(a).text());
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/MmPTn/)

Comment: THAT WAS IT!! prevAll traverses in the reverse order and as it collects multiple elements, first() grabbed the first one it came across in that reverse order. Thanks so much.

Comment: and finally found

Comment: @karthickeyan glad to know that :)

Answer (score 2):

You may try this

```
$('.subsection').prev('.slide:not(".subsection")');
```

[**An Example here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/dBHXZ/1/)

Comment: This failed in my tests, since .prev only selects the 1st previous  element and I can't assume that $('.subsection') will get the required element since there could be lots of subsection elements in the real example (under p2 and p4 etc) so it may not necessarily get the correct subsection element... note in the above $subsection = $('#p32') - Not sure if that was clear in my eg.