# Search <select> before multiple elements before <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I search the `select` element before multiple elements before `<a>`?

I know  `$('select[name=foo]').val())`

```
    <select name="foo">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">3</option>
      <option value="2">3</option>
    </select>

    <div class="foo2"></div>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>

    <a class="button" href="#">Search</a>
```

This is my attempt:

```
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).prevUntil('select'));
});
```

Comment: Do you need selected value in foo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery find closest previous sibling that does not have class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19723221/jquery-find-closest-previous-sibling-that-does-not-have-class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [prevUntil](http://api.jquery.com/prevuntil/) will get you all elements up to the element in the selector

FROM DOCS:

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element up to but not including the element matched by the selector, DOM node, or jQuery object.

You want to use `prevAll('select:first')` to get the first previous select
http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

> Description: Get all preceding siblings of each element in the set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector.

```
$(this).prevAll('select:first')
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/5zK2y/)